# Why is this regex finding slashes?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, expression

```
[^A-Za-z0-9(\\)@% \"]
```

I want this regex to find everything except all those characters in there? it works for most but it's finding slashes.

Comment: please add the code where you are creating and using this regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to escape the slash for it to be matched `("[^A-Za-z0-9(\\)@% \"]")`

how is this defined in the code?  as a string literal?  If not you might not be escaping the escapes correctly.  Try with an @ at the front, as the regex as is seems to work ok for me and not match the '\' character.

I think you are doing this

```
string pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9(\\)@% \"]"
```

Try like so:

```
string pattern = @"[^A-Za-z0-9(\\)@% \"]"
```

you migth find [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gusperez/archive/2005/08/10/450257.aspx) useful if that is the issue

Comment: I think I copied it wrong, I have it like you do up there, that doesn't work.

Comment: @Joey G, updated answer, can you say how you are declaring your regex.

Comment: It's just finding a match. So if it matches, basically it will find a special character because it is NOT finding all of the characters above. I don't want it to find slashes but it is.

Comment: @Joey G, as I said please show us the code where this is used.  I tested it on nregex.com and it doesn't match the \ in 'blah \'

Answer (score 0):

Because the `\` is a special character an needs to be escaped: `\\`

`"[^A-Za-z0-9(\\\\)@% \"]"`